# KendoGrid: Virtual scrolling with detail item

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

Virtual scrolling works fine, as soon as we don't introduce a detail item template on it.
Actually is not working, are there any plans to have it in the next future?

Comment: My fault, it works but only if using `detailRowHeight` input ;) Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/F2MHhEI9TvSogy2xwa1o?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have found out, virtual scrolling needs to know the height of the items, in order to function properly. This is so that the scroll size is correctly calculated, based on the content size -- if these are not in sync, the user experience is quite frustrating. This is documented in the [scroll modes section](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/#toc-scroll-modes) of the documentation.